# How to change the image size within a Drupal view

Tags: views, 8

Does anybody know the best way to change the image size of a field within a view using Drupal 8?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create an image style at admin interface and then use same style at your view settings.

Navigate to `admin/config/media/image-styles` and add new style. After that edit image field inside your view which will look like below image.[image]

In image you can see Image style which you have created in earlier step. This way you can change the image sige at views.

Comment: perfect answer +1